# Http exception in jsoup

Tags: java, exception, jsoup

Http exception in jsoup.

```
org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=503, URL=http://google.com
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:418)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:393)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:159)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:148)


Document doc;
doc = Jsoup.connect("http://google.com").timeout(300000).get();
```

Tried various solutions but none of them worked.

Answer (score 3):

Did you [look up](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) what 503 means ?

> 10.5.4 503 Service Unavailable
>
> The server is currently unable to handle the request due to a
>   temporary overloading or maintenance of the server. The implication is
>   that this is a temporary condition which will be alleviated after some
>   delay. If known, the length of the delay MAY be indicated in a
>   Retry-After header. If no Retry-After is given, the client SHOULD
>   handle the response as it would for a 500 response.

Given that it looks available from here, do you have a proxy/gateway in place that isn't available ? I would use some network tool (traceroute, perhaps?) to track where this is coming from.

Comment: How can I set the length of the delay in Jsoup?

Answer (score 2):

```
document = Jsoup.connect(UrlRequest).timeout(30000).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.120 Safari/535.2").get();
```

You can try this for delay by changing timeout